# checking out a Git repository and switch to a specific branch using Maven SCM

Tags: git, maven, version-control

I would like to use Maven to checkout a Git repository.
In our specific use-case this makes sense as this Git Repository contain files that we need to include in out build process.

Due to the nature of projects it is likely that the Git repository has different branches. So a simple:
    
        scm:git:git@github.example.com:myproject/project.git

Will not work as this will checkout master. I would like for example branch "3.0V3"

Is there a way I can specify which branch Maven will checkout?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `<scmVersion>` and `<scmVersionType>` properties of [maven scm plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkout-mojo.html) to achieve this.

```
 <scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:url</developerConnection>
  </scm>
 ...

 <build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.8.1</version>
          <configuration>
              <connectionType>developerConnection</connectionType>
              <scmVersion>branch-name</scmVersion>
              <scmVersionType>branch</scmVersionType>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: That is right, I guess the complete list of parameters is here: http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkout-mojo.html I just wonder how to modify the checkout directory name. Maven will always use target/checkout as the local name. I would rather like target/branch-name as directory. The "workingDirectory" parameter seems to have no effect (at all).

Comment: Ahh nevermind :) The "checkoutDirectory" is the parameter for that. http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkout-mojo.html#checkoutDirectory

Comment: I don't like this answer because it demands changes to pom.xml just to change which branch will be built.

Comment: @SteveCohen. You can pass `-DscmVersionType` and `-DscmVersion` as command-line parameters to your `mvn scm:update` or similar task, if you do not want to change `pom.xml`.